# MySQL Workbench: 'Disk Space in Data Dir' limited to 20G

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mysql, hosting

I have an OVH private server (Ubuntu 12.04, 8 GB RAM, i3-2130, 2x500 GB HDD) and I'm dealing with MySQL administration. I have installed MySQL Community server 5.6.16 correctly and it works fine(it responds all the queries requested by a tomcat server). However, when I check 'Server Status' in MySQL Workbench there is a parameter called 'Disk Space in Data Dir' with a '13G of 20G avalaible' value.

I use a laptop with Windows 7 and no partitions (one 1 TB HDD) to develop and try changes in a local copy of this server. Here, when I check this parameter in MySQL Workbench, it shows '782.00 GB of 911.00 GB avalaible'.

My current my.cnf file: http://pastebin.com/Gfw53Lbi

So, I guess it's something related to partitions or the way OVH has formatted the hard disk space. Any ideas?

---

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  6,3G   13G  33% /
/dev/root        20G  6,3G   13G  33% /
none            789M  252K  788M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md2        911G  9,1G  856G   2% /home
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the output of `df -h`

Comment: My df -h shows: http://pastebin.com/zzMt3szj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the df -h output shows that your server is partitioned so that the /home directory has most of the space on the hard disk.

A quick and dirty fix would be to move the mysql data directory from /var/lib/mysql to /home/mysql/ and then change my.cnf accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try it. Anyways, which would be the most elegant solution? I'm just a developer and I ignore most of the administration details but I'd like to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Elegant solution would be to make a new partition for the MySQL data directory, and then mount it to /var/lib/mysql directory. Another option is to re-install the whole system and allocate space differently.